# Garbage Collector Behavior for Destructor

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a simple class that is defined as below.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I Still Exist!";
    }

    ~Person()
    {
        p = this;

    }
    public static Person p;
}
```

In Main method

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Person();
        x = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine(Person.p == null);

    }
```

Is garbage collector supposed to main reference for Person.p and when exactly will the destructor be called?

Comment: First: a destructor in C# is ment to be a **finalizer**. Second: setting your singleton-instance to the instance being finalized seems like a **very very bad idea**. Third: what is `Person1`? I see only `Person`. Last: see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors for how finalizers work.

Comment: @HimBromBeere `Person1` is actually `Person`, fixed the typo.

Comment: @HimBromBeere This was actually an interview question, now as per my understanding, CG.Collect should have invoked destructor but it didn't .

Comment: (1) If you re-reference the object being finalized inside it's finializer, then IT WILL NOT BE GARBAGE COLLECTED until that reference is no longer reachable from a root (so this has the effect of delaying its garbage collection). (2) The point in time when a finalizer is called is not predictable.

Comment: @HimBromBeere and when i put breakpoint at Console.WriteLine Person.p is coming up as null, regardless of `GC.Collect` call

Comment: @MatthewWatson this makes a bit of sense to me now.

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ Yes, the problem is, however, trying to write code that actually demonstrates it. As you have noticed, trying to set the object in the finalizer doesn't actually seem to extend the lifetime. You end up actually having to wait longer - I'll see if I can find a way to actually demonstrate it properly!

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Thanks, i'll try to find something on this as well. Cannot find much on MSDN related to this.

Comment: @MatthewWatson when running under debugger i can see destructor being invoked when Main has completed execution.

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ Yep, that will happen for .Net framework - but note that for .Net Core then finalizers ARE NOT RUN AT PROGRAM EXIT!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The thing you are missing here is that the compiler is extending the lifetime of your `x` variable until the end of the method in which it is defined - that's just something the compiler does - **but it only does it for a DEBUG build.**

If you change the code so that the variable is defined in a separate method, it will work as you expect.

The output of the following code is:

```
False
True
```

And the code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Finalizable
    {
        ~Finalizable()
        {
            _extendMyLifetime = this;
        }

        public static bool LifetimeExtended => _extendMyLifetime != null;

        static Finalizable _extendMyLifetime;
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            test();

            Console.WriteLine(Finalizable.LifetimeExtended); // False.

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Console.WriteLine(Finalizable.LifetimeExtended); // True.
        }

        static void test()
        {
            new Finalizable();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically your understanding was correct, but you didn't know that the sneaky compiler was going to keep your variable alive until *after* you called `GC.Collect()` - even if you explicitly set it to null!

As I noted above, this only happens for a DEBUG build - presumably so you can inspect the values for local variables while debugging to the end of the method (but that's just a guess!).

The original code DOES work as expected for a release build - so the following code outputs `false, true` for a RELEASE build and `false, false` for a DEBUG build:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Finalizable
    {
        ~Finalizable()
        {
            _extendMyLifetime = this;
        }

        public static bool LifetimeExtended => _extendMyLifetime != null;

        static Finalizable _extendMyLifetime;
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            new Finalizable();

            Console.WriteLine(Finalizable.LifetimeExtended); // False.

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Console.WriteLine(Finalizable.LifetimeExtended); // True iff RELEASE build.
        }
    }
}
```

---

As an addendum: Note that if you do something in the finalizer for a class that causes a reference to the object being finalized to be reachable from a program root, then that object will NOT be garbage-collected unless and until that object is no longer referenced.

In other words, you can give an object a "stay of execution" via the finalizer. This is generally held to be a bad design, though!

For example, in the code above, where we do `_extendMyLifetime = this` in the finalizer, we are creating a new reference to the object, so it will not now be garbage-collected until `_extendMyLifetime` (and any other reference) no longer references it.